# Liquibase change log is not being applied in next server restart

Tags: sql, jhipster, database-migration, liquibase

I have following master.xml and changelog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include file="config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="config/liquibase/changelog/20180616032541_changelog.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

20180616032541_changelog.sql

```
--liquibase formatted sql
begin;
INSERT INTO jhi_authority(name) VALUES ('ROLE_MANAGER');
end;
```

What I assume is during next server restart, my sql should automatically be applied.

But record is not being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The changelog didn't included changeset metadata.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset author:pmverma authority_add:1
begin;
INSERT INTO jhi_authority(name) VALUES ('ROLE_MANAGER');
end;
```

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html